# "Sticky key" bug again

Tags: keyboard, 14.10

Every time I hit a key very fast twice, it starts repeating. It hapens very often with backspace key but I can repeat this with any key.

I am running ubuntu 14.10 (installed from minimal iso image 30MB)
I have xfce window manager. My host computer is laptop dell latitude e7240 with windows7.

This does not happen in host os ever, so its not about the keyboard itself.
Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: I noticed that I do not need to hit a key even twice. I starts repeating everytime when the key is touched very fast, so that key-press and key-release events are very near each other. So somehow the key-release event is missed if it happens right after key-press event.

Comment: Try with the below command and check whether the sticky key accepeted after upgradation:gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-enable true.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable keyboard stroke repeating via the UI

> Settings -> Universal Access -> Typing -> Repeat Keys

or from the [command line like described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860655/how-to-stop-keyboard-repeat-on-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

Host is Windows7!..Is it a VirtualBox or VMWare?

Because I have similar case with VBox, when using sticky keys; modifiers do not switch well (following unactive → latched → locked cycle), sometimes missed sometimes duplicated. It seems like a bug in VBox keyboard filter/driver.

A workaround: Use a USB keyboard and attach it directly to the virtual machine.