# Sticky keys driving me crazy

Tags: keyboard

I have a problem with sticky keys, even though I turned them off, randomly it starts to repeat the key, and it is very annoying when it is backspace or delete, and I see everything I wrote getting deleted.

That's why I turned the repeating keys option completely off, but it is not perfect. ( as described here : https://askubuntu.com/a/1117772/996929)

Does anyone have any solution?
Running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: Does this happen with different keyboards?

Comment: I haven't tried but the same computer was with windows 10 and back then I didn't have this problem. I don't think it is because of the keyboard.

Comment: Depending on the definition of back then it could have broken since then. Also what kind of keyboard is it? Could be drivers.

Comment: Keyboard is a laptop keyboard from Dell Latitude E5440.

Comment: if it's connected to your laptop, putting it in the dishwasher is a bad idea,  try a different keyboard and see if the problem persists...